# Copy sub-arrays of NULL-terminated array of strings

Tags: arrays, c, string, null

Suppose I have an array of 'array of strings':

```
{"hello", "I", "am", "C", NULL, "And", "I", "am", "C++", NULL, "Now", "this", "is", "Java", NULL, NULL}
```

How may I extract out the `NULL`-terminated sub-arrays from this array, so that I can have the following:

```
char* arr1[] = {"hello", "I", "am", "C", NULL}
char* arr2[] = {"And", "I", "am", "C++", NULL}
char* arr3[] = {"Now", "this", "is", "Java", NULL}
```

This array itself is passed as an argument to a function, like so:

```
void function(char* strings[])
{
    int index = 0; 
    loop: 
    while(strings[index])
    {
        if(!strings[index + 1]) break;
        // how can I add stuff to an array? 
        ++index;
    }
    if (strings[index] || strings[index + 1]) goto loop;
    // Now what? 
}
```

EDIT: I'd like *actual* copies of the strings, possibly by way of `strdup()`.

EDIT 2: My attempt added, since this was asked for (and I ought to have provided it at the outset). Furthermore, the function does *not* need to return anything: all processing is done within and the strings are discarded (or stored elsewhere) afterwards, hence the `strdup()`.

Comment: You should just loop over the input array, and end a subarray when you find a NULL.

Comment: Should only pointers be copied or do you need to have the actual strings also copied?

Comment: What have you tried and where did you get stuck exactly?

Comment: It is impossible to know how many null-terminated arrays of strings will be in the result. The return type of `function` should be `char***` instead of `void`.

Comment: OT: It seems a rather bad idea to store the substrings in 3 different arrays. Doing that means that the function wont be able to handle input with 4 or 5 or ... or 100 substrings. Use an array of pointers to arrays of char pointers.

Comment: Anyway - for this task `realloc` is your friend

Comment: One first step could be to determine the number of string arrays in the result, which can be done by counting the `NULL` values in the input and allocate space accordingly.

Comment: @4386427 I have added some additional information and a first attempt.

Answer (score 0):

I have an attempt:

```
char*** group_strings(const char *strings[])
{
    uint index = 0;
    uint start_index = 0;
    uint num_groups = 0;
    uint *group_sizes = NULL;
    char ***grouped_strings = NULL;

    do
    {
        while (strings[index])
        {
            if (!index || !strings[index - 1]) start_index = index;
            if (!strings[index + 1]) break;
            ++index;
        }

        group_sizes = !group_sizes ? (uint *) calloc(++num_groups, sizeof(int))
                                   : (uint *) realloc(group_sizes, ++num_groups * sizeof(int));
        uint current_grp_size = index + 1 - start_index;
        group_sizes[num_groups - 1] = current_grp_size;

        char **current_argument = (char **) calloc(current_grp_size, sizeof(char *));
        for (int i = 0; i < index + 1 - start_index; ++i)
        {
            current_argument[i] = strdup(strings[start_index + i]);
        }

        grouped_strings = !grouped_strings ? (char ***) calloc(1, sizeof(char **))
                                           : (char ***) realloc(grouped_strings, (num_groups - 1) * sizeof(char **));
        grouped_strings[num_groups - 1] = current_argument;

        index += 2;
        if (!strings[index - 1] && !strings[index]) break;
    } while (strings[index] || strings[index + 1]);
    return grouped_strings;
}
```